# android java.lang.VerifyError on startactivity in 1.6

Tags: android

I implement a project which contain a activity group mainActivity.
This main activity contains 3 other activity groups.

When I try to start myaccountactivity which is an activitygroup, it works for api more than 1.6 but if i tried to run it on 1.6 i get following wrror

```
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412): java.lang.VerifyError: com.myproject.android.MyAccountActivity
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1472)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1097)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2316)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2242)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:127)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:339)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.myproject.android.myproject.showMyAccountAtivity(myproject.java:396)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.myproject.android.myproject.onActivityResult(myproject.java:456)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:3625)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityGroup.dispatchActivityResult(ActivityGroup.java:123)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3220)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3266)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2600(ActivityThread.java:116)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1823)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549)
11-23 12:22:15.005: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(412):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I tried to fins out solution but no use. Please if anyody knows how to solve or knows reason why it is coming let me know..

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using functions from an SDK past 1.6, but you claim in your manifest that your app runs fine on 1.6. Set your build target to 1.6 to see which ones.

Comment: Have a look at this blog post on the Android Developers blog on how to handle onBackPressed() in versions of Android prior to 2.0: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/12/back-and-other-hard-keys-three-stories.html

Comment: I use super.onBackPressed() which causes verify error in 1.6 but runs smoothly in version 2.0 and more. Sorry for the previous answer.